# Electric field on conductor surface

Tags: electric-fields

Having searched around I came to the conclusion  that the electric field on the surface of a charged conductor is undefined as in there is a discontinuity but is there a way to explain it **intuitively** without the use of complex formulas? I have been unable to comprehend the answers to similar questions on this site.

Comment: Did you see [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/175765/26969) to a similar question? Does that clear things up for you?

Comment: Well  having read it I have the same question - if The transition from zero to finite electric field takes place at a point right where the surface of conductor shell starts. So where is the discontinuity and why is it there.